# PI 2 - GPIO pin stays HIGH even when I toggle ( in Java)

Tags: gpio, java

Hi my first Java program to control a LED has failed, the LED does not come on even though the pin state is continuously HIGH ?

Heres the Java code :-

```
final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
System.out.println("Setting GPIO_04 as output");
final GpioPinDigitalOutput led = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin( RaspiPin.GPIO_04 );
boolean currentState = false;
for (;;) {
    Thread.sleep( 1000 );
    System.out.println("Current state is " + led.getState());
    led.toggle();
}
```

This prints out :-

```
Setting the GPIO_04 as output
Current state is HIGH
Current state is HIGH
Current state is HIGH
```

etc...
??
What am I doing wrong ? why is the state continuously HIGH and why isnt the LED on ? (It comes on if I connect to the 5v or 3.3v pins so the circuit is ok)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use the correct pins?  There is a difference between the old Rev1 and Rev2 GPIO layout so you might used a wrong reference.

If you plan to do loads of led GPIO, the time to designa GPIO LED overview board might save you a lot of time in the future.

A good reference for pin layouts is http://wiringpi.com/pins/  However actual GPIO numbers might differ depending on which lib you're using.

Comment: Im using pi4j version 0.0.5 I wonder if it needs updating for PI 2 ? <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.5</version>

Comment: Yes it does, updating to version 1.0 and it works beautifully. Thanks for your rapid reply.